# how to import image base64 in css

Tags: css, image, base64, base64url

Is it possible to somehow import the image base64 from another file? or save the url to a variable and import it to CSS? since the code is very long and it does not seem clean in this way.

Thank you for your help guys.

index.css

```
    .column {
      margin: calc(var(--grid) / 2);
      border: var(--borderWidth) solid #fffddd;
      border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
    
      
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.769),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.961)),url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QDWRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAEPAAIAAAASAAAAPgEQAAIAAAAMAAAAUIKaAAUAAAABAAAAXIdpAAQAAAABAAAAZAAAAABOSUtPTiBDT1JQT1JBVElPTgBOSUtPTiBENTEwMAAAAAAKAAAMgAAFgpoABQAAAAEAAACigp0ABQAAAAEAAACqiCcAAwAAAAICgAAAkAMAAgAAABQAAACykgoABQAAAAEAA...
```

Comment: Don't post images. Post your actual code.

Comment: Sorry, just edited, thanks.

Comment: Great. I upvoted your answer. Thanks for complying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is to use [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()) CSS from  inside another CSS file that you can import .

File myCssVar.css

```
:root {
--mybguri64: url(data-image/jpeg;base64, ... ) ; 
}
```

Your CSS file

```
@import url(myCssVar.css);

.column  {
background-image: linear-gradient( ....), var(--mybguri64) ... ; 
}
```

It will make your CSS easier to read.
Looks like from your edit you almost had it .

Comment: Thank you very much, it was just what I was looking for, I wish you an excellent day!

Answer (score 0):

Background-image's URL is a string value. Of course, you can store it in another file, import it and use js to inject it dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I wish you an excellent day!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to that is to use the server side script with an inline css to make this happen.  to make this happen. lets say the backend language is php. and your pages are made up of 3 templates components. It could be in different backend languages either ASP.net, Javs, php, node... but i'm using php here since i'm vast in it. just follow through its quite simple and direct.

- base64ImageFile.php  - the file with the base64image variable it could be more than 1
- header_template.php
- footer_template.php
- application.php

then in your base64Images.php you have this there..

```
<?php 
   
    $base64Img ='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7';

    $base64Image2 = 'data:image/png;base64,sgw....';
    $base64Image3 = 'data:image/png;base64,sgw....';
    $base64Image4 = 'data:image/png;base64,sgw....';
?>
```

**in my header_template.php, add the template to the beginning of the file.. **

```
<?php 
    require('base64images.php');   //the images are rendered here.. 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     li {
         background:url(<?php echo $base64Img; ?>) <!-- and used here --->
          no-repeat
          left center;
          padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
       }
    </style>
</head>
```

**in my footer_template.php**

```
<!---  footer elements/scripts go here  --->
 <script src="...."></script>
 <script src="..."></script>

</html>
```

**application.php** - file, merge template components to build page here

```
<?php require('header_template.php'); ?>

<body>
    .......body content coes here... 
</body>

<?php require('footer_template.php'); ?>
```

this way you can re-use and seperate the components and even seperate images into different files and call them. in your file instead of typing it out. or even multiple images... but the CSS must be inline with the HTML..

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Ande, I wish you an excellent day!